# Can Java Play framework store more than 100KB of a request in memory without writing to disk

Tags: java, playframework

I'm working on a throughput-intensive application, and in trying to identify the bottlenecks, I found that writing the request body to disk and then reading it back in when the entire request is received is a pretty slow operation.

My sending side will send me data up to 512KB in one HTTP POST and that can't be changed, so I'm looking for ways of handling it better on the server.  In debugger I see, that Play uses RawBuffer class to manage incoming data and that class has *memoryThreshold* field, which is currently set for 100KB.  Does anyone know of a way to programmatically or via a configuration file to change this default to be 512KB?

*Update:*
Things I've tried with no success:

- Entering "parsers.text.maxLength=512K" in the application.conf file.
- Just for kicks and giggles "parsers.raw.maxLength=512K" and "parsers.raw.memoryThreshold=512K" in application.conf
- Adding "@BodyParser.Of( value = BodyParser.Raw.class, maxLength = 512 * 1024 )" annotation to my action method.
- All three application.conf property names above with "512288" instead of "512K"

Comment: I see a _.toInt() call which makes me think that 512K won't work. Try a correct integer.

Comment: about to try, but this was based on Play's documentation: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaBodyParsers

Comment: Very right, the code I pasted in my answer below comes straight from the AnyContent trait; if that is the case, we shall ask to update the documentation.

Comment: @AlessandroSantini: that was a good guess :) ...but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If I look at the code I read

```
lazy val DEFAULT_MAX_TEXT_LENGTH: Int = Play.maybeApplication.flatMap { app =>
  app.configuration.getBytes("parsers.text.maxLength").map(_.toInt)
}.getOrElse(1024 * 100)
```

which makes me think that the `parsers.text.maxLength` property is the one you look for.

Comment: Updated the question.  That was the first thing I tried and it didn't work. I'm suspecting that attribute only works with text-based parsers (text, xml, json...)

Comment: I don't know what `toInt` does, but I'd check if it actually handles the "K" suffix, maybe you need a pure integer there.

Comment: You may be quite right, however I see a .toInt() call that makes me think it needs a valid integer.